# Can i get rotation from this matrix algorithm

Tags: c++, math

Can i get rotation(yaw , pitch,roll) from this matrix algorithm ?
thanks

```
matrix[0][0] = cos(pitch)*cos(yaw);
matrix[0][2] = cos(pitch)*sin(yaw);
matrix[0][1] = sin(pitch);
matrix[0][3] = 0;
matrix[1][0] = -cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw)+sin(roll)*sin(yaw);
matrix[1][1] = cos(roll)*cos(pitch);
matrix[1][2] = -cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw)-sin(roll)*cos(yaw);
matrix[1][3] = 0;
matrix[2][0] = -sin(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw)-cos(roll)*sin(yaw);
matrix[2][1] = sin(roll)*cos(pitch);
matrix[2][2] = cos(roll)*cos(yaw)-sin(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw);
matrix[2][3] = 0;
matrix[3][0] = 0;
matrix[3][1] = 0;
matrix[3][2] = 0;
matrix[3][3] = 1;
```

edit : i used this code but it not working :

```
D3DXMATRIX matrix2 = D3DXMATRIX(matrix);
yaw   = atan2(matrix2._13, matrix2._11);
pitch = asin(matrix2._12);
roll  = atan2(matrix2._32, matrix2._22);
```

Edit 3:
this is my old function , it works but not 100%

```
VECTOR getAnglefromMatrix(float* m)
{
    float pitch, yaw, roll;

    D3DXMATRIX matrix = D3DXMATRIX(m);

    if (matrix._11 == 1.0f)
    {
        yaw = todegree(atan2f(matrix._13, matrix._34));
        pitch = 0;
        roll = 0;
    }
    else if (matrix._11 == -1.0f)
    {
        yaw = todegree(atan2f(matrix._13, matrix._34));
        pitch = 0;
        roll = 0;
    }
    else
    {

        yaw = todegree(atan2(-matrix._31,matrix._11));
        pitch = todegree(asin(matrix._21));
        roll = todegree(atan2(-matrix._23,matrix._22));
    }

    return vector3d(yaw,pitch,roll);
}
```

i did something wrong ?

Comment: I bet the `yaw`, `pitch` and `roll` variables in the code shown represent their respective concepts. Beyond that, I don't understand what you may be asking.

Comment: thanks for your response, this is a matrix algorithm, i want to extract rotation info from matrix directly.

Comment: So you're you looking to reverse the function shown?

Comment: yes and sorry if i was bad in explanation ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can go through the entries and find some that are nice for back-calculations:

```
matrix[0][0] = cos(pitch)*cos(yaw);
matrix[0][2] = cos(pitch)*sin(yaw);
```

This gives us:

```
yaw = atan2(matrix[0][2], matrix[0][0])
```

For the pitch:

```
matrix[0][1] = sin(pitch);
```

This gives us:

```
pitch = asin(matrix[0][1])  //this assumes pitch is between -pi/2 and +pi/2
```

Then

```
matrix[1][1] = cos(roll)*cos(pitch);
matrix[2][1] = sin(roll)*cos(pitch);
```

This gives us:

```
roll = atan2(matrix[2][1], matrix[1][1])
```

I omitted the cases where the arguments to `atan2` become zero. I am confident you can figure them out. In these cases, the Euler angles are not uniquely defined.

Comment: i can't get it working , can you see my edited post ? thanks

Comment: Why do the two pieces of code use different naming schemes (`matrix[i][j]` and `matrix._ij`)? Might the mapping be wrong? Also, in the last code snippet you use `todegree`. Please show an example where it "does not work". It would have been easier if you had posted your code right from the beginning.

Comment: it works , thanks . the problem is in another function that cause some wrong value.